# Is there a way to recover data after using Data Loader

Tags: apex, backup

One of the users accidentally make an mass upload using data loader, total 40000 records, this mass update has affected 15 000 records and some data has been lost. This is really bad for the org, because those are sales for the last 2 days. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to back up the system, we do back ups once a week but that won't help in this case.

I will appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did the Mass Upload consist of and how did it affect the records?

You could upload the same file, matching on a unique field and delete those 40k records.

You could also run a report on the 15k that were affected and update them if you know what changed (if it's only a few fields, potentially field history tracking was on).

Other than the weekly backup, that's all I can think of at the moment!

Comment: The mass update consist on placing 0 to one field that was null. But one work flows ruined 15 000 records, we had history tracking on. How do i get these values and re-uploaded?

Comment: You should be able to create a new Report - "Object History" - replacing Object with whatever your load affected (Case, Account, etc).  Then you can filter the report to only show the specific field that was changed from 0 to 1 at the time of the load as well as show the field that was updated via workflow (assuming it's on the same object).  Then add the record id to the report, export and transform in Excel, and update those 15k records.